# I have to prevent the rest of the page from scrolling when the mouse is inside a bootstrap popover scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this bootstrap popover that allows users to put inline comments on my site:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBMGh.png

There is a scrollbar on the top-right side. If a user scrolls down in the box and hits the bottom, then the page behind it will start to scroll. Is there any way to prevent the user from scrolling the main page when this popover is in focus/being scrolled?

Accepted solution in my context:

```
            $('.my-class').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
                $('.popover-title').hover(function(e) { //popover title is
                //the scroll window in the popover

                    $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
                }, function() {
                    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
                });
            });
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: 15px; 
    //hides scrollbar without moving the body over
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the body's css attribute `overflow` to `hidden` that should stop the user from being able to scroll the body.

```
function disableScroll() {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}
function enableScroll() {
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I posted the code in my context above.

Answer (score -1):

```
//prevents keyboard scroll
function noScrollEvt (e){
    if (e.keyCode === 40 || e.keyCode === 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
};
//use this function to disable scroll
function disable () {
    $('selector')
    .on('keydown', noScrollEvt)
    .css('overflow', 'hidden');
}
//use this function to enable scroll
function enable () {
    $('selector')
    .off('keydown', noScrollEvt)
    .css('overflow', '');
}
```